# Calculating Finite Population Standard Deviations from an ANOVA with an interaction effect

Tags: bayesian, anova

Recently, I've been working with Bayesian models with categorical predictors - ANOVA-esque models, if you will. I've been greatly intrigued by [Andrew Gelman's work on the subject](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1112967698) looking at finite population standard deviations.  I've also found lots of inspiration from [this excellent set of tutorials by Murray Logan](http://www.flutterbys.com.au/stats/tut/tut7.4b.html). This has raised two questions

1) Is calculating the finite population SD (for fixed and random effects) really just as easy as taking the SD across coefficients (one sd per draw from the posterior)? Or multiplying a slope coefficient by the sd of the relevant predictors?

2) That said, how do we handle interactions? For an interaction slope, I would merely multiply the posterior draw of the interaction coefficient by the sd of the product of the relevant predictors. But, for categorical-predictor-only models... This is a conundrum.

Consider the following model.

Say you have a model with two sets of predictors - treatment and block. There are two treatment levels, and 10 blocks.

For the model y ~ treatment * block given that you have treatment contrasts, you’d have the following coefficients

Intercept (treatment A in block 1)
Treatment B (deviation from treatment A in block 1)
Block 2 through 10 (deviation of treatment A in Blocks 2-10 from treatment A in block 1)
Treatment B * Block 2 through 10 (The deviation of treatment B in blocks 2-10 from treatment B in block 1 + the additive effect of being in block 2-10)

Given this formulation, sd(treatment) makes sense as the sd of the posterior of treatment B and 0 - it’s no different than if we had the SD of treatment A and B’s posteriors. (i.e. sd(a1, b1), sd(a2, b2), etc - to be clear)

Same for sd(block) - sd(0, treatment 2, treatment 3, treatment 4, …)

But - that interaction - given that we’re looking at the unique contribution of the interaction to the overall sd of y, and we’ve accounted for the sd due to the main effects of treatment and block, don’t we want the unique effects of the interaction? Since we’re working with treatment contrasts here, each additive piece is a reference condition, with the interaction as the deviation.

So - wouldn’t it be 0, repeated once for the intercept, once for the treatment B deviation, and 9 times for the additive effect from blocks 2 through 10, and then all of the interaction terms?

This generalized to an n-way interaction, as all of the lower-order terms are 0, and then we include the highest order interaction coefficients as well.

Hrm. Or, should we have *all* of the additive and interaction coefficients and a single 0 for the reference condition here?

Comment: Are you really talk about the finite population as indicated in title?

Comment: Yes. See the linked references.

Comment: The second link has no "finite". The first link misused the term "finite population" because there is super-population for each his finite population.